# Do we have license issue for @font-face generated fonts?

Tags: css

I've been using font face generator for quite sometime, a few weeks ago my client asked me to use a commercial font family (not open source) fonts and he provided ".ttf" format. I used font face generator to generate remaining font formats (eot, woff2, woff. svg), currently I am confused whether font formats generated are licensed ?

Comment: Legal questions pertaining to copyrights, licensing, etc. are off-topic on StackOverflow

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing instead of directly about programming. [[See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1402846)] for details and the [[help]] for more.

Answer (score 1):

Well, each font comes with their own license (EULA). So when you use them in commercial websites, you should double check the license of the particular font. Because web font generators won't take any responsibility. But you have to.

e.g. https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

There you can see the agreement checkbox with the text:

> Yes, the fonts I'm uploading are legally eligible for web embedding.

Hope this helps. :)